# VC++ what does return code do?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I have a code. like this:

```
int functionA (){
    Foo(**,**,**);
    return 0;
}
```

Foo() is a huge function(more than 10,000 lines). Which I don't understand all.Foo function includes some multi-thread code.

The problem now is, if I have "return" code right after Foo, Foo can be run correctly.

If I insert some other code (even a really simple cout code) between Foo() and "return". The Foo function will act weird(partly not run correctly).

I debugged this thing for 3 days. Nothing found.

Comment: My crystal ball is broken. I'm afraid you will have to supply more details.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan :p  sorry, i am afraid of i cant. As a muggle, I do with meet some prophet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I insert some other code (even a really simple cout code) between Foo() and "return". The Foo function will act weird(partly not run correctly).

Sounds like `Foo` is corrupting the stack in some way.  You'll probably find that declaring redundant variables (and hence changing the contents of the stack) "fixes" the problem.

I'd look for a tool that finds memory problems in your code.  If you don't have such a tool, look *really* carefully at all the usages of allocated memory.

Comment: thanks, I will try tomorrow when I go to office. Really confused about this thing. never met this before. thanks for your advice